IOptionMonitoring<>.OnChange not triggered on some K8s Pods
I am using .net6.0 And I want to monitor some changes from the configuration files and react to the changes.
I have the following code to register the config file:
{
...
new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine("folderPath", "file.json"), false, reloadOnChange: true))
    .Build();
...
}

Then I have a service that is Injected as Singletone.
public class Notifier : INotifier
{
    public Notifier(IOptionsMonitor<Model> monitor){
        monitor.OnChange(config => Log("file changed"))
    }
}

This code, locally is working fine.
In  K8s there I have multiple pods, and the file.json is shared among the pods. That means, if I change the file.json in one place, it is automatically changed in all the pods.
If I go to Pod #1 and I manually change the file. This code detects the changes and it logs the message, but only on that Pod. The file gets changed everywhere but OnChange method is not triggered on the other pods.
Do you have any idea what might cause the issue?
